# dispatch_async -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, dispatch-async

I can't fix this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' ***`

Any ideas on how I can do this?

It seems that the error is caused by the initialization of arrays.

The first time that the method is executed, does not show any problem. The error occurs only on the second time.

**Dispatch_Async Method**

```
-(IBAction)clickRandom:(id)sender{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self RequestJson];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

**RequestJson Method**

```
-(void)RequestJson
{
    Name = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    slug = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    image = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    view = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    category = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

        NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
        array = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"videos"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
        {
            [Name addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [slug addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"slug_video"]];
            [image addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"thumbnail_video_original"]];
            [view addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"views_video"]];
            [category addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"category_name_video"]];

        }
       [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
```

As the crash log is this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2d77de7e __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x37ada6c2 objc_exception_throw + 34
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d6b3d90 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 228
3   Vigg                            0x00117a40 -[DEMOHomeViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (DEMOHomeViewController.m:315)
4   UIKit                           0x30034310 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 404
5   UIKit                           0x2ffdc6c8 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1796
6   UIKit                           0x2ffdbeec -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 180
7   UIKit                           0x2ff0234e -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 342
8   QuartzCore                      0x2fb8893e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 138
9   QuartzCore                      0x2fb84162 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 346
10  QuartzCore                      0x2fb83ff4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
11  QuartzCore                      0x2fb83a08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
12  QuartzCore                      0x2fb8381a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
13  QuartzCore                      0x2fb7d548 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2d748f64 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 16
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2d7468f2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2d746c3e __CFRunLoopRun + 734
17  CoreFoundation                  0x2d6b146c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2d6b124e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
19  GraphicsServices                0x323eb2e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
20  UIKit                           0x2ff66840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
21  Vigg                            0x000f84c0 main (main.m:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x37fd3ab2 tlv_initializer + 2
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have an empty array somewhere.

Comment: It would help if you could post the full backtrace for your exception. Try setting a breakpoint on "All Exceptions" and looking at the backtrace in Xcode or by using the command "bt".

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2d77de83 0x37ada6c7 0x2d6b3d95 0x110d45 0x30034315 0x2ffdc6cd 0x2ffdbef1 0x2ff02353 0x2fb88943 0x2fb84167 0x2fb83ff9 0x2fb83a0d 0x2fb8381f 0x2fb7d54d 0x2d748f69 0x2d7468f7 0x2d746c43 0x2d6b1471 0x2d6b1253 0x323eb2eb 0x2ff66845 0xf1705 0x37fd3ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Add the symbolicated crash log to your question (not as a comment).  This will show how you got the the problem and will help people find the issue.  To get the crash log, setup the Exception breakpoint in Xcode and re-run your app.

Comment: Point out which line of code is actually causing the problem. It's none of the code you posted so far.

Comment: And don't call the `reloadSections:` method at the end of `RequestJson`. 1) It's being done on the background - that's bad. 2) You call `reloadData` immediately after anyway so what's the point?

Comment: I added the Crash Log

Comment: if you want the code to be asynchronous (that is advised) then utilize `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:` instead of wrapping your synchronous code with GCD

Answer (score 1):

The crash is in your table view's data source methods and is not in the `RequestJSON` method (which should be called `requestJSON`;  methods always start with lower case letters).

Therefore, you have an empty array where you don't expect it and you have decoupled the count of rows (or sections) in your table view from the data model object that actually contains the data.

You'd need to post the source of the method that is actually crashing.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a UIKit method on a background thread and that's causing a random crash.  Replace this line

```
[tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

with these lines (moved from clickRandom to requestJson)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [tableView reloadData];
});
```

Either that, or wrap the `reloadSections` call in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`

Answer (score 0):

I did a little refactoring with some suggestion to handle the error and view response

```
- (void)someMethodCalledInViewDidLoad_viewWillAppear_orLoadView_beforeRequestJson
{
    name = [NSMutableArray array];
    slug = [NSMutableArray array];
    image = [NSMutableArray array];
    view = [NSMutableArray array];
    category = [NSMutableArray array];
}

-(void)requestJson
{
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
    array = [jsonArray objectForKey:@"videos"];
    // you can log your jsonArray or array to see what values are present or not
    if (array.count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
        {
            [name addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]];
            [slug addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"slug_video"]];
            [image addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"thumbnail_video_original"]];
            [view addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"views_video"]];
            [category addObject:[[array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"category_name_video"]];

        }
       [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   }
}

-(IBAction)clickRandom:(id)sender{
    [self requestJson];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty array. You tried to call [array objectAtIndex:0]. 0 is beyond the bounds of an empty array (anything is beyond the bounds for an empty array).